# TypeScript compilation error with Firebase 5.9.0

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication, ionic3, angularfire2

I am enhancing an Ionic-Angular 3.9.2 PWA app that uses Firebase. I am trying to add Apple Signin as a feature into this app. I am following the approach for the integration as documented here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple.
My project also uses AngularFire2.

In order to support the Apple signing I upgraded Firebase web SDK from 4.8.0 to 5.9.0 and have upgraded AngularFire2 from 5.0.0-rc.4 to 5.0.0-rc.6.

While trying to run the project (with ionic serve) I get the following Typescript error

```
typescript: src/providers/authenticata/authenticata.ts, line: 266
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

 L265:  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 L266:    var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("apple.com");
```

When I check the definition of the OAuthProvider I do see that it has a property called providerId that is takes.

```
class OAuthProvider implements firebase.auth.AuthProvider { providerId: string; /** * @param {string} scope Provider OAuth scope to add. */ addScope(scope: string): firebase.auth.AuthProvider;
```

Incidentally I noticed that If I ignore this error, add a comment in the file and save to compile again and reload the app, it works without throwing an error.

While trying to a do a build for deployment the Angular AOT compiler again throws this issue.

```
[15:11:16] typescript: src/providers/authenticata/authenticata.ts, line: 266
Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

 L265:  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
 L266:    var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("apple.com");
Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above.
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "pwa": "ionic-app-scripts build --prod --platform browser && gulp build-sw",
    "browser": "ionic-app-scripts serve --sourceMap source-map --iscordovaserve --wwwDir platforms/browser/www/ --buildDir platforms/browser/www/build"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.2",
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/date-picker": "4.5.2",
    "@ionic-native/firebase": "4.5.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "@types/intro.js": "2.4.5",
    "@types/moment": "2.13.0",
    "@types/underscore": "1.8.7",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.6",
    "clipboard": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-ios": "5.0.0",
    "device": "0.3.9",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "4.2.2",
    "firebase": "^5.9.0",
    "ics": "2.13.1",
    "ics-js": "0.10.2",
    "immutable-ics": "0.4.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionic-img-viewer": "2.9.0",
    "ionic-plugin-deeplinks": "1.0.20",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "2.2.1",
    "ionic2-auto-complete": "1.6.2-alpha",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "ng-lottie": "0.3.2",
    "node-sass": "4.6.0",
    "promise-polyfill": "7.0.2",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "workbox-sw": "3.1.0",
    "ws": "3.3.2",
    "xcode": "2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3",
    "@types/googlemaps": "3.36.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.2",
    "workbox-build": "4.3.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "config": {
    "ionic_copy": "./config/copy.config.js"
  },
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-datepicker": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {}
    },
    "platforms": [
      "browser"
    ]
  }
}
```

My code is as below

```
import { AngularFireDatabase } from "angularfire2/database";
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
..
..
async signInWithApple() {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
var provider = new firebase.auth.OAuthProvider("apple.com");
firebase
.auth()
.signInWithPopup(provider)
.then((result) => {
// I handle the firebase auth and other logic here
})
...
```

My environment and CLI versions are as below :

```
username$ ionic info

cli packages: (/Users/gofloaters/.nvm/versions/node/v8.13.0/lib/node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
global packages:

Cordova CLI : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1) 
local packages:

@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 8.1.0 browser 6.0.0 ios 5.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.9
System:

Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.4 
Node              : v8.13.0
npm               : 6.4.1 
OS                : macOS
Xcode             : Xcode 11.2.1 Build version 11B500
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you also add links to the documentation you got this code from in the question ?

Comment: I got the code for integrating Firebase with Apple authentication from https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/apple